# How to call a module in python

Tags: python, python-import

This is not really a python question, but rather seeking assistance on interpretation of the syntax in my python code. I have very little knowledge of python.
I have a call to an external module (i.e. external to python) as follows:

```
from icclim import icclim.util.callback as callback
```

When I run my code, I get the error

```
from icclim import icclim.util.callback as callback
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have the icclim software installed and I see on the directory structure there is

```
$HOME/icclim-master/icclim/util
```

Inside the util dorectory I see among the files there is

```
callback.py
callback.pyc
```

My thinking is that it is one of these two files being called.
The command

```
from icclim import icclim
```

works.
My question is how should I make the call to callback, or do I have to set any path to callback?
assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: `from icclim.util import callback` should suffice

Comment: what about import ```from icclim.util import callback``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from icclim.util import callback` does the trick.

You can only navigate through subpackages by "." symbol between "from" and "import" statements, so first you're navigating to "icclim.util" subpackage and then importing "callback" from there.

Comment: Thanks @Shishmarev and the same answer also by Greluchon and MjZac. I believe that is the correct answer. But then it throws me another error on a different line, which is   from . import set_globattr
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: @ZiloreMumba see this question about this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Answer (score 0):

`from icclim import util.callback` it is enough for your problem.

See details: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html